# jQuery getJSON method on older mobile web browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-website

I am using jQuery's getJSON method to display content on a mobile website page. It works fine on current browser versions of Chrome, Android 2.2+ and mobile Safari, but not displaying at all on Blackberry versions 5 & 6, Windows mobile (mobile IE) 7, and Android (browser) 2.1.

Can anyone help? I've set up a fiddle with my current function here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hyperdouche/krqNP/

EDIT: just wondering if there is something in the function or in using the getJSON method that these older browsers can't understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm assuming the first line with the colon instead of '=' isn't present in the version your using successfully because that should break everywhere unless it's a property of an object literal in your real code.

"internetIndex: function() {"

Old mobile IE is basically IE7 so I'm not sure why JQuery would have a problem there. Perhaps a security issue peculiar to the platform?

Blackberry is well-known for being a ginormous PITA. You may want to do some research there. I know JQ Mobile wouldn't touch blackberry or mobile IE support when it first came out but I think that had to do more with media queries.

One thing that helps a lot in getting feedback on ajax requests in more primitive environments is crockford's JSON object normalizer (the JSON object is standard in newer browsers).

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

With that in your code you can do JSON.stringify to the data and if it's reasonably well formed you should be able to spit it out as a string for debug.

You might also just want to try a more basic core JavaScript ajax function to verify that it's not framework related. They're not that tough to write and there's plenty of examples out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The colon is part of an object literal - but you've given me an idea on how to isolate it a bit better, I might take it out and use a basic function to see if I can get any results that way. Thanks